# How to add UI element to a specific position for different screens for Android App?

Tags: android

I'm working on converting an `ios app` to an `Android App` and encountering an `UI` question.

As the image shown below, I want to put two plain texts under **`SCORE`** and `**BEST`**. But the problem is everything is the background image, even the black boxes.

Previously, I hard coded the texts' margins but those number will be at different positions for different screens since I want the image align horizontally to the screen. Am I forced to use coordinate to solve the problem at the run time?

If so, would it kill a lot memory?

[image]

Comment: user `RelativeLayout` and its `LayoutParams` to add the item on specific Relative location

Comment: Having everything in the background image will lead to a huge amount of frustration on the wide variety of Android devices out there. Just segment your background into separate images.

Comment: Highly recommending to get rid of your background image.

Answer (score 0):

Slice the image into smaller parts and make them the background of own views. Calculate then the correct ratio for every image/view. Apply the ratio to the width and height of the views by using the layout params programmatically or using xml. If you tie everything together, make the dynamic texts etc. part of the views and put them at the appropiate positions. I recommend to use relative layouts.

Comment: I just saw that ianhanniballake already added kind of the same answer before me, but as a comment. (I had the edit dialog open for a while). If he/she will post this as an answer, he should be rewarded in the first place.